# Generate WADL or any XML documentation for Ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, wsdl, wadl

Is there possibility to generate WADL/WSDL from an existing Ruby on Rails project? Need to test the security
Or to generate some kind of documentation for controllers
https://github.com/austvik/wadlgen is too old and doesn't work